# Baremetal Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, real-time

I have a strange request: I would like to boot my application directly onto the Samsung Galaxy S4 hardware, without booting the Android OS (in other words, baremetal operation).
I can use this for my own research, specifically in time-critical applications.

Does anyone know if there is a framework already in place which allows this baremetal development? Or if not, any tips?

Also, has anyone succeeded in turning Android into a RTOS?

Any ideas or tips will be welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Devendra

Comment: Go look at how the alternative android versions do it, e.g. cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 4):

You can't run applications on an Android device without the OS being booted. It's like - I want to use Photoshop as soon as I start my PC, but without the Windows booting.

Comment: Baremetal allows you to have the application boot as if it were the kernel. I have doing it regularly with Intel's Single Chip Cloud Computer.

Comment: The question is - what was the device? It wasn't an android device for sure.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking that it should be possible to do the same with the hardware inside Samsung Galaxy S-IV (as an example). Specifically, the question is how to boot a custom application directly onto the hardware, and if there is a framework that already exists. If this is too much of a hack, an option would be use custom ROMs as @MarcB already suggested. Thanks a lot for your answer, anyway!

Comment: That is of course if you consider the custom ROM as an "application", but it is that framework you're talking about. What I mean is that the custom ROM (as well as the stock Android OS) is an operating system ("framework") which is designed to work with the specific hardware of the device (phone, tablet etc.). If you want to interact directly with the hardware, you'll have to build a custom ROM as well, which is not an application, but an OS.

Comment: I highly DONT recommend doing this as it requires ALOT of experience and you WILL MOST LIKELY brick your device attempting this, but for the sake of knowledge here it goes. if you want to go bare metal, its do-able. First, find out what chip is running on your device, then find out its exact booting sequence (ie what loads first, what is kind of bootloader is required) for example the rpi1s GPU loads the a file called kernal.img to a specific address in ram and the hands over to the processor ... so if you want to go bare metal on the pi, you just replace the kernal.img file with your own

Comment: However, the pi boots from a sd card(rewrite it), a laptop has many booting options(all re-writable), ur device doesnt. Just the internal flash memory ... & if u mess up JUST ONCE & dont successfully load a working "kernal" so to speak, that initializes the usb port, enables usb mass storage device emulation of the internal flash memory (so u can rewrite it) ... thats it !! Its bricked as u wont be able to access the memory again & load the correct code, its not a MCU development board, these have dedicated hardware (ICSP) to write the memory directly without involving the processor at all

Comment: Yes you can. Inside the smartphone is ARM Cortex-A or similar. You need to develop drivers for the screen and keyboard and any peripheral the phone has and you want to use but this is hard as hell...